# group by + case when in other column with pandas

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a data model with three columns (CUST_ID, TOPIC, VALUE)

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"CUST_ID":["C1", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C3"],
                       "TOPIC":["TOPIC1", "TOPIC2", "TOPIC2", "TOPIC1", "TOPIC2"],
                       "VALUE":[10, 15, 8, 5, 20]})
```

I want to group by CUST_ID, transform column "TOPIC" into two columns "TOPIC_a_VALUE" and "TOPIC_b_VALUE"

I know how to do it by SQL, but how to do it by pandas?

```
SELECT CUST_ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TOPIC = "TOPIC1" THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS TOPIC_a_VALUE
       MAX(CASE WHEN TOPIC = "TOPIC2" THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS TOPIC_b_VALUE
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CUST_ID
```

The result I want is below,

```
result = pd.DataFrame({"CUST_ID":["C1", "C2", "C3"],
                       "TOPIC_a_VALUE":[10, np.nan, 5],
                       "TOPIC_b_VALUE":[15, 8, 20]})
```

Comment: Could you please post how your final output looks like by using a random data

Comment: @Sumanth I add original data and result by pandas data frame

Comment: there is no `TOPIC = "a"` in the original data , please add so we can replicate

Comment: @anky_91 I modify typo, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps more readable than the other suggested answers, I would go with:

```
data.groupby(['CUST_ID', 'TOPIC'])['VALUE'].max().unstack()
# Output
#TOPIC   TOPIC1 TOPIC2
#CUST_ID              
#C1        10.0   15.0
#C2         NaN    8.0
#C3         5.0   20.0
```

If you prefer, you can of course rename the columns:

```
.rename(columns={'TOPIC1': 'TOPIC_a_VALUE', 'TOPIC2': 'TOPIC_b_VALUE'})
```

Comment: Yes, this is better. Couldn't think of this last night. +1

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you need something like:

```
df=data.pivot_table(index=['CUST_ID','TOPIC'],columns=['TOPIC']).reset_index()
df.columns=[''.join(col) for col in df.columns.values]
df.loc[df.CUST_ID.duplicated(keep=False)]=df.loc[df.CUST_ID.duplicated(keep=False)].bfill()
df=df.drop_duplicates('CUST_ID')
df=df.drop([col for col in df.columns if 'Key' in col],axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)

  CUST_ID   TOPIC  VALUETOPIC1  VALUETOPIC2
0      C1  TOPIC1         10.0         15.0
1      C2  TOPIC2          NaN          8.0
2      C3  TOPIC1          5.0         20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't make sense in SQL.  I assume you intend something like this:

```
SELECT CUST_ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TOPIC = 'a' THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS TOPIC_a_VALUE
       MAX(CASE WHEN TOPIC = 'b' THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS TOPIC_b_VALUE
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CUST_ID;
```

That doesn't directly help with the Pandas solution, but at least the query will make sense.

Comment: Thinks @Gordon Linoff, I forget aggeration function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` in following way:

```
df=data.pivot_table(index=['CUST_ID','TOPIC'],columns=['TOPIC']).reset_index()
df.columns=[''.join(col) for col in df.columns.values]

df1 = df.groupby('CUST_ID').ffill()\
        .groupby('CUST_ID').last()\
        .reset_index()
```

To clean out the dataframe

```
df1 = df1.drop(columns = ['TOPIC']).
rename(columns{'VALUETOPIC1':'TOPIC_a_VALUE','VALUETOPIC2':'TOPIC_b_VALUE'})
```